# I have {get; set;} methods for all my properties, but I keep getting an error of "A get or set accessor expected"

Tags: c#

Sorry if this seems dumb, but I've looked through other questions regarding this issue and I can't find anything. I'm transitioning from Java to C#, so I'm probably missing something to do with properties that I would have just done using methods in Java.

In Monodevelop, I keep getting

> A get or set accessor expected

as an error when I compile.

Here's my code.

Program.cs:

```
class MainClass
{
    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        Transaction myTransaction = new Transaction ();
        string[] data = Console.ReadLine ().Split(',');
        while (data[0] != "#") {
            myTransaction.Name = data [0];
            Double.TryParse (data [1], out myTransaction.Cost);
            Int32.TryParse (data [2], out myTransaction.Quantity);
            Console.WriteLine (Transaction);
            data = Console.ReadLine ().Split(',');
        }
    }
}
}
```

Transaction Class:

```
using System;


public class Transaction
{
    //private vars//
    //string name;
    //double cost;
    //int quantity;

    //Constructor//
    public Transaction ()
    {

    }

    //Properties//
    public string Name{ get; set;}
    public double Cost{ get; set;}
    public int Quantity{ get; set;}

    //methods//
    public double CalcTotal(){
        return Quantity * Cost;
    }

    public override String ToString{
        return String.format("{0:0.00} x {1:0.00} @ ${2:0.00} Total: ${3:0.00}", Name, Quantity, Cost, CalcTotal()); 


    }
}
}
```

Comment: In the future it would be helpful if you pinpoint *where* you get that error.

Comment: Apologies. The error occurs at 

...return String.format("{0:0.00} x {1:0.00} @ ${2:0.00} Total: ${3:0.00}", Name, Quantity, Cost, CalcTotal()); ...(pardon my markdown). Monodevelop highlights the return method, but I don't see how this actually relates to return.

Comment: You can *[edit]* your question to add more information, make it more clear where the error is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your ToString method, you forgot `()`

```
public override string ToString () {            
    return string.Format("{0:0.00} x {1:0.00} @ ${2:0.00} Total: ${3:0.00}", Name, Quantity, Cost, CalcTotal());                
}
```

Also you have couple more problems:

```
Console.WriteLine(Transaction);
```

should be

```
Console.WriteLine(myTransaction);
```

And properties can't be `ref` and `out` parameters

See working [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OqTjps)

Comment: sigh :( , beat me to it... this is the correct answer

Comment: Thanks, this is the correct answer.(Stuck in java) However, someone also pointed out that I can't use TryParse(***, out ***) with an object property. This seems a bit strange but I was able to fix this by assigning it to a variable then passing that to the property.

Answer (score 2):

The issue you are having is with (I am assuming) is with your parse statements. You cann't pass an `out` or `ref` as a property or indexer of a class.

```
Transaction myTransaction = new Transaction();
string[] data = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
while (data[0] != "#")
{
    myTransaction.Name = data[0];
    Double.TryParse(data[1], out myTransaction.Cost); //<-- this is the issue
    Int32.TryParse(data[2], out myTransaction.Quantity); //<-- here again
    Console.WriteLine(myTransaction);
    data = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
}
```

What you will need to do is hold the value in a seperate variable and then assign it to the `Transaction` object as.

```
Transaction myTransaction = new Transaction();
string[] data = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
while (data[0] != "#")
{
    myTransaction.Name = data[0];

    double dCost;
    int dQty;

    Double.TryParse(data[1], out dCost); //<-- this is hte issue
    Int32.TryParse(data[2], out dQty); //<-- here again
    myTransaction.Cost = dCost;
    myTransaction.Quantity = dQty;
    Console.WriteLine(myTransaction);
    data = Console.ReadLine().Split(',');
}
```

So as you see we have created two additional variables in the loop `dCost` & `dQty` during the loop the values are parsed to the local variables, then these variables are set to the instance of the Transaction `myTransaction`.

In addition there are two other small issues with the code.

1. The override `ToString` should be a method as `ToString()`
2. The method `string.format(..)` is actually `string.Format()`

Finally as others pointed out `Console.WriteLine(Transaction);` should be `Console.WriteLine(myTransaction);`

Comment: Thanks, this was a secondary issue, but not the one the error actually applied to. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems with your code:

1. Your `ToString` method is lacking its parenthesis, the `return` statement inside is likely the one giving you the error you refer to in your question
2. `String.Format` is written with a lowercase `f`, `String.format`, which won't compile.
3. You cannot use `ref` or `out` parameters and target properties, you must target variables, like local variables or fields.
4. `Console.WriteLine(Transaction)` cannot write the *class*, it must write an *object*, so you likely want to use `Console.WriteLine(myTransaction);`.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are passing a property of the class as a `ref` and `out`. You can't do this, because C# can't know is there a backend field behind the Property.Why ??? You can simply have this property like

```
public double Cost
{ 
   get { return 4.5; } 
   set { /* empty */ }
}
```

And here what will do `CLR` with your `out` and `ref` parameters?It can't set any value to the property.

```
 Double.TryParse (data [1], out myTransaction.Cost);
 Int32.TryParse (data [2], out myTransaction.Quantity);
```

And here you need

```
Console.WriteLine (myTransaction);
```

not

```
Console.WriteLine (Transaction);
```

and the `ToString(`) must be

```
public override string ToString(){
     return String.format("{0:0.00} x {1:0.00} @ ${2:0.00} Total: ${3:0.00}", Name, Quantity, Cost, CalcTotal());     
}
```

Comment: Ok, but that's not the problem. Sorry, I hadn't actually debugged the main class fully. Thanks for picking that up but it's not the fault with the accessor.